# Installing QGIS3 on a Mac with Python in Anaconda

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, anaconda

I am trying to install QGIS3 via Kyngchaos installer. But as I install python 3.6 in anaconda, the installer cannot find it. I know I can install a new environment or use symlinks to connected to Python that installed by `homebrew` as suggested in [Installing QGIS3 on Mac?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274381) But as I have already installed a lot of packages in anaconda environment, I still hope to connect QGIS libs to it. Is it possible to do that?

Python 3.6 is installed in `/Users/.../anaconda3/bin`

Comment: The KyngChaos packages specifically say they are only compatible with Python.org python, not Anaconda/Homebrew/MacPorts/etc... Conda-forge are [trying to package QGIS for anaconda](https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues/17).There is a test build you can try by conda-forge contributor gillins, try `conda install -c gillins qgis` or to avoid issues `conda create mynewenv -c gillins qgis`

Comment: which python3.6.? did you use for standard python

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share my experiment though I still failed to install it.

It seems in my case that The python path should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`. I try to create a symlink like `ln -s  /anaconda3/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` and then I can 'successfully' install QGIS3.

However when I open QGIS3 that I have installed. It crushed suddenly when loading the software without any dialog box showing any errors or warnings.

I am still wondering whether there are some libraries that I should install besides GDAL and what's the reason for its crush.

Comment: It might be worth trying to link the actual `Python.framework` locations - e.g. QGIS3 looks for python at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Next thing to confirm is whether you install the KyngChaos GDAL after (as opposed to before) linking the python location? Lastly, install `pygments`, `owslib`, and `jinja2` in your anaconda environment and see if that helps. Do the crash logs provide any clues as to specific missing packages?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked the path and install pygments, owslib, and jinja2 but it still crushed after `checking provider plugins` without showing any dialog boxes.

Comment: There might be some underlying conflict between Anaconda versions of gdal and related packages and those provided by KyngChaos.

Comment: I simply installed Python 3.6 via the python installer and didn't set any environment variables.  The QGIS install worked without changing my default Python package (i.e. launching python from terminal launches Anaconda).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried `ln -s /Users/sergio/anaconda3/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` and QGIS won't find Python 3.6...

Answer (score 0):

Just download python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and reinstall python 3 again. It works for me!