# Missing osgeo in QGIS 3.4 Madeira (macOS High Sierra)

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, installation, osgeo

I am trying to install QGIS 3.4 on my Mac. When I open QGIS I get a message that osgeo is missing.

> Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

**Here are the steps I've gone through:**

1. I installed Python 3.6.8, per QGIS's instructions

> This distribution requires Python 3.6 (only python.org Python 3 is supported, another python 3 installation can't be substituted, ONLY the MOST RECENT 3.6, not a later 3.7+).  Python must be installed before installing QGIS.

2. I installed the packages named in the QGIS readme using `python3 -m pip install packagename`

> Some Python modules are required and installed using pip from files in the installer.  Modules will be upgraded if already installed.  Installed modules include (plus any dependencies):
>
> owslib, PyYaml, psycopg2, jinja2, pygments, numpy, plotly

3. I then installed QGIS without hiccup
4. When I opened QGIS I was warned of an error (full log at end of question)
5. Looking online I found that osgeo is a part of the GDAL package and that this is a common problem for installing *QGIS 3.0*. However, for QGIS 3.0 the install includes a step for installing GDAL before QGIS but this step and dmg is lacking in version 3.4.
6. Still, I downloaded GDAL and ran the dmg file. GDAL (and subsidiarily osgeo) is now in my Library/Frameworks folder.
7. Still, though when I run QGIS I receive the same error.
8. Not knowing how Python works (I've used a previous version of QGIS and never needed Python – why do I need it now?) I went to Terminal again and ran `python3 -m pip install gdal` but this resulted in error:

> ... No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f1/_nnmjmr53_s39dc46sfkj10w0000gn/T/pip-install-suyzpo9n/gdal/

I presume that I need to activate osgeo or gdal somehow but I don't know how. I'm surprised by how difficult this install is, especially for a program that doesn't require command line work once inside, and which previously had a much easier install.

**QUESTION:**

- My ultimate question is how do I install QGIS 3.4 on macOS
- I believe though the answer is that I need to install gdal, so my question becomes how do I install in gdal in a way that QGIS recognizes.

**Many questions already exist about similar problems when installing QGIS but almost all of these are for QGIS 3.0, in which GDAL is a part of the installation process. I am asking for QGIS 3.4. with related scenarios but different problems / different versions**

Comment: Per another question I tried using homebrew but ran into another error. Feel very over my head but also confused that the water should be so high https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274381/installing-qgis3-on-mac

Comment: waw. Amazing. It's like on month i'm stuck with "no module os geo" and no "processing", finally it works. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157955)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by:

- removing both `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework` and
  `/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework`
- downloading the old QGIS 3.0 installer from [here](https://www.qgis.org/downloads/macOS/)
  and installing *only* GDAL_complete, not QGIS itself.
- after that, downloading the latest unified installer (3.4.3-2 as of writing, same page above)
  and runing the setup again.

Rather crude approach but I was fed up fiddling with those libraries.

Comment: Thanks @johwag, I'm on my phone now but will try this!

Comment: Yup worked for me.