# QGIS install on OSX with homebrew: "You have other linked versions!"

Tags: qgis, osx, homebrew

I have an OSX Mojave setup where I've already installed PostGIS and GDAL using Homebrew.

Now I'd like to install QGIS. I'm trying:

```
brew install qgis
```

But... I'm getting lots of warnings of the form:

```
osgeo-postgis: You have other linked versions!
```

I'm using PostGIS in various projects, so I would prefer to avoid breaking / version-changing anything that's currently running if possible, though I can do so if absolutely necessary.

What do I need to do to install QGIS?

Here's the full output:

```
==> Installing osgeo-qgis from osgeo/osgeo4mac
osgeo-proj: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink proj or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies proj

osgeo-libgeotiff: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink libgeotiff or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libgeotiff

osgeo-libspatialite: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink libspatialite or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libspatialite

ant: Java 1.8+ is required to install this formula.
JavaRequirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install java
You can download from:
  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
osgeo-netcdf: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink netcdf or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies netcdf

osgeo-postgresql: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink postgresql or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies postgresql

osgeo-gdal: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink gdal or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies gdal

osgeo-postgis: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink postgis or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies postgis

osgeo-grass: XQuartz 2.7.11 (or newer) is required to install this formula. X11Requirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install xquartz
You can download from:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org
mesa: XQuartz 2.7.11 (or newer) is required to install this formula. X11Requirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install xquartz
You can download from:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org
osgeo-openscenegraph: XQuartz 2.7.11 (or newer) is required to install this formula. X11Requirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install xquartz
You can download from:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org
freeglut: XQuartz 2.7.11 (or newer) is required to install this formula. X11Requirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install xquartz
You can download from:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org
osgeo-proj@5: You have other linked versions!

Unlink with brew unlink proj or remove with brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies proj
```

Comment: duplicate? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274557/112869

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured it out. You did `brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac` before and thereby expanded your brew with the osgeo-tap. The [repository documentation](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac#renaming-formulae) mentions they are currently 'renaming' formulae. It turns out they're renaming formula `postgresql` to `osgeo-postgresql` etc. So my trick was to type on the shell:

```
for f in libgeotiff libspatialite netcdf postgresql gdal postgis sip qscintilla2 pyqt; do brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies $f; done
```

This will uninstall the currently installed relevant formulas from osgeo. Next, install the formulae with the new name (prefixed with osgeo-) with:

```
for f in libgeotiff libspatialite netcdf postgresql gdal postgis sip qscintilla2 pyqt; do brew install osgeo-$f; done
```

Once finished, you should be able to install `osgeo-qgis` with:

```
brew install osgeo-qgis
```

- if it fails with `Error: Too many open files @ rb_sysopen` , do a `ulimit -n 1024` first
- it will take a while, the amount of direct/indirect dependencies is quite large

Answer (score 0):

The best way is install qgis by a package downloaded from https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/download.html !!!

The answer from [ivy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319653/47761) fix the "You have other linked versions" problem, but after that are any other dependencies problems. The package installation on the other hand is plug an play - no dependency issues!!!